# PowerPoint 2007 Print Dialog via C#

Tags: c#, dialog, printing, powerpoint

We have C# code in a PowerPoint Addin for custom printing. In Office 2003,

```
SendKeys.Send("^+{F12}");
```

works fine to bring up the Print Dialog after doing some stuff.

But in Office 2007 it does not, instead just sending the document to the printer without the dialog.

Getting the Dialog is very important.

using "^{p}" or "^p" as the string will acheive the same thing, no dialog.

Executing the command via:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FilePrint");
```

will also acheive the same thing, no dialog.

Any clues, tips or suggestions as to how can I may get the Print Dialog to appear would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, here's how I was able to eventually get this working, but i dont fully understand why.

three things required (all necessary)
- use ExecuteMso instead of SendKeys
- remove code prior to print which selected a particular slide
- add call to Application.DoEvents() after ExecuteMso()

Also works OK with Select code restored, but after the Print call, and also including a DoEvents() call.